# Concat two IF statements

Tags: excel, if-statement, concatenation

I have 4 columns.

Column H is a Manual Entry column

Column I (New Business/Lost clients) and J (organic growth/organic decline) are both IF statements that I have formulated

Column K has a Concat formula which I need to pull a list of both Column I and J into . e.g. if something is in column I but not J then that will make part of the list (vise versa.(if you can think of a better way happy to hear it).

However, if I enter something in the 'Manual entry' column I need that to take the place/overwrite the IF statement columns in column K.

Basically I need column I and J combined but can be altered if I enter manual data

[image: Example]

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would help if you would mock up some data and expected output showing all the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Enter array formula in K2 as follows `=INDEX(H2:J2,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(H2:J2),0))`  press ctrl+shift+enter to make it an array formula.  then fill down.

This basically says find the first non-blank value in H, I, J and use it.  So if H is populated it will use it.  If not it looks to I and uses it if populated if not it uses J. If nothing's populated you get #NA

But upon re-reading the question maybe you need I/J to be combined...  so back to example.

Comment: So close! thanks @xQbert, it is picking up Column I data but not Column J. Any reason why this may be?

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 options.  Firstly:

```
IF(ISBLANK(H2), J2 & K2, H2)
```

Or, using code you've already used in Column K:

```
IF(H2="", J2 & K2, H2)
```

N.B. `CONCAT` and "&" do pretty much the same thing - use `CONCAT(J2, K2)` **or** `J2 & K2`, not both at once (`CONCAT(J2 & K2)`)